# comparing two addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-design, dapps, ethereumjs

I'am trying to create a modifier that allows certain accounts to execute functions.

```
 address[] authorized; 
       function verify (address adrs) internal view returns (bool)
{
    bool exist;
    uint  j=authorized.length;
    uint i =0;
    exist = false;
    address[] memory adrss;
    while (i<j){
        uint x =0;
        if (adrss ==address[i]){
            bool = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return exist;
}



  modifie allowed (address adrs){
        require  (  verify(adrs)==true);
                    _; }
```

anyone how has an idea?

Comment: Hi there. I haven't tried it, but it's clear the above code doesn't compile. Is your question "How do I get this code to compile?" or, more generally, "What is the best way to implement an ACL?". Please be more specific with your question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid iterating the list of permitted accounts. It's an expensive approach that doesn't scale and it has a lot of moving parts.

Consider instead using a `mapping`. This is a namespace where all the uninitialized indexes return `false`, `0`, `empty`, depending on type. For example:

`mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;` returns `true` or `false` for each address, and you can set/get without iterating.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract SimpleWhitelist {

    address public owner;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;

    event LogProtected(address sender);

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner.");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyWhitelist {
        require(whitelist[msg.sender], "You are not whitelisted.");
        _;
    }

    function setPermission(address user, bool isAllowed) public onlyOwner {
        whitelist[user] = isAllowed;
    }

    function protected() public onlyWhitelist {
        emit LogProtected(msg.sender);
    }    
}
```

There are more advanced ways to store the list of whitelisted addresses: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity) and de facto standard implementations of the `Ownable` concept but I wanted to keep this as simple as possible.

1. Only the owner is allowed to grant/revoke permission.
2. Only whitelisted addresses are allowed to run `protected()`. It will emit an event on success.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a fundamental mistake which makes it all seem much harder than it really is.
Instead of an array, your should use a mapping(address => bool), let's call it `whitelisted`.

Add people in the whitelist like this: whitelisted[_address] = true;

then in your modifier, you can simply do this:

```
require(whitelisted[_address]);
```

Comment: No need to convert through `uint160)`. `if(addr1 == addr2) { ...` should work if both are addresses.

Comment: You are correct, that trick is useful for comparing short Strings cheaply, and I made some confusion. I edited out that part, as anyway it was slightly besides the OP's topic.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you look at the OpenZeppelin guide on Access Control, specifically the section on Role-Based Access Control as using Roles from OpenZeppelin appear to meet your needs.
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/access-control

For questions on use, you can also ask in the community forum https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/