# comparing addresses to determine "ownership" of a contract not working as expected

Tags: solidity, addresses

I am trying to write a function to determine if the address msg.sender is the same address as the wallet that deployed the contract. I know that this is typically done via the the OpenZeppelin Ownable contract. As an exercise I wanted to see if I could make some of the logic myself.

The essential pieces are

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;
contract MyFund {

    mapping(address => Investor) public investors;
    address public manager;

    constructor(
        string memory _fundName,
        uint256 _installmentAmount,
        uint256 _numOfInstallments,
        uint256 _noOfInvestors
    ) public {
        fundName = _fundName;
        numOfInstallments = _numOfInstallments;
        noOfInvestors = _noOfInvestors;
        manager = msg.sender;
        installmentAmount = _installmentAmount * 1e18;
        jackpot = SafeMath.mul(installmentAmount, noOfInvestors);
    }

    modifier isManager() {
        require(msg.sender == manager, "Only the manager can access this function");
        _;
    }

    function checkIfManager() public view returns (bool) {
        if(msg.sender == manager){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
.
.    
.
```

I looked at this question, and it looked like my approach should in theory work?
[comparing two addresses](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72570/comparing-two-addresses)

I just want to compare msg.sender (which is of type address) with manager (which is also of type address, using == for comparison.

I would think, if I deployed the contract with a metamask wallet, and then called the checkIfManager() function from the same metamask address, that it would return true, but that is not the case and I have no idea why.

I deploy the contract out to rinkeby and I have some FE code to call the checkIfManager function, and everything LOOKS like it aligns, between the manager address and my own address

[image: FE code saying that checkIfManager is returning false]

But according to that code, where my current address is the in top right corner, and the  manager address is on the bottom, that function is returning false, and I am very confused by this. Is there something I am missing for how to compare two addresses for equality?

Edit: based on a comment by Ismael, the FE sets up the call to the view func like this

```
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setAccount(accounts[0]);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const networkData = MyFund.networks[networkId];
    if (networkData) {
      const myfund = new web3.eth.Contract(
        MyFund.abi,
        networkData.address
      );
    viewIsManager = await myfund.methods.checkIfManager().call();
```

Comment: How are you calling `checkIfManager`? For `msg.sender` to work reliably in a call to a view function you have to explicitly set the from parameter. Some frameworks use as default the zero address, others fail if it is missing.

Comment: That is a good point. I am using the web3 package in a react app.
I think this is the call you are referring to, yes?
const viewIsManager = await myfund.methods.checkIfManager().call();

Which is set up like
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setAccount(accounts[0]);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const networkData = MyFund.networks[networkId];
    if (networkData) {
      const myfund = new web3.eth.Contract(
       MyFund.abi,
        networkData.address
      );

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js and @usedapp, you could do something like this:

```
export function IsManager(address: string | Falsy) {
    const [isManager]: any =
    useContractCall({
        abi: interfaceAbi,
        address: tokenAdrress,
        method: "manager",
        args: []
    }) ?? [];
    return isManager;
}

const { account } = useEthers();
const etherBalance = useEtherBalance(account);
const isManager = IsManager(account);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the comment by Ismael, I updated the FE function call from

```
const viewIsManager = await chitfund.methods.checkIfManager().call();
```

To

```
const viewIsManager = await chitfund.methods.checkIfManager().call({from: accounts[0]});
```

Which did fix the behavior. This was not an obvious assumption to make about calling view functions vs other kinds, but the solution makes sense.